# Get `ValueError: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers` from namedtuple

Tags: python

I run the code

```
from collections import namedtuple
ChinaHistoryOutline =  namedtuple('ChinaHistoryOutline',['1. 封建社会篇', '2. 豪族社会篇', '3. 古代平民社会篇','4. 近代转型篇','5. 现代革命篇','6. 中国崛起篇' ])
```

got `ValueError`

```
    ValueError: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers: '1. 封建社会篇'
```

There's no problem with the list

```
In [8]: ['1. 封建社会篇', '2. 豪族社会篇', '3. 古代平民社会篇','4. 近代转型篇','5. 现代革命篇','6.  中国崛起篇' ]
Out[8]: ['1. 封建社会篇', '2. 豪族社会篇', '3. 古代平民社会篇', '4. 近代转型篇', '5. 现代革命篇', '6. 中国崛起篇']
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `1. 封建社会篇` is not a valid name for a **variable**. That's what the `identifier` means. `封建社会篇` is a valid name.

Comment: Also it doesn't make *any sense at all* to make a named tuple of a list

Comment: Yes,I am trying `dict` to process chapters and sections. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: why would you have 1. 封建社会篇 ? Is 封建社会篇 value or the variable name ?  This is how named tuple is used Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender')  ; bob = Person(name='Bob', age=30, gender='male')

Comment: The names of the tuple are not *data*. 封建社会篇 is a heading or a category. It shouldn't be a field in a tuple. The fields of a tuple are *set in stone*, they're as if they'd be mathematical. 封建社会篇 is not. 封建社会篇 is data. It might be rather static data, but it is data nevertheless. Use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error trying to use namedtuples for autofill in jupyter notebook of dataframe column names. My column names had invalid characters listed below. The following renaming of columns via re module replaced all invalid characters with "_" and

```
import re
df3.columns=[(re.subn("[/' ()-]","_",x))[0] for x in df3.columns.to_list()]
df3.columns=[x.replace("_","n",1) for x in df3.columns.to_list()] 
#cant start name with underscore so change first underscore to "n" character also
```